# PHP/HTML Table Not Functioning Properly

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm having problems getting my PHP file to function properly. It is supposed to display a two-columned table containing departments (unordered list) and department categories (ordered list beneath each department).

The result at the moment is that the SECOND column is appearing perfectly fine, with the bulleted unordered list and numbered ordered lists beneath each bulleted department. The FIRST column, however, is being displayed WITHOUT any bullets or numbers. The data is there, but not in the format (ul and ol) that I was expecting.

Thanks for you help. Let me know if you need more information.

```
<?php
//displayDepartments.php
$query = "SELECT * FROM product_categories_reference
    ORDER BY department_name DESC";
$category = mysql_query($query)
    or die(mysql_error());
$numRecords = mysql_num_rows($category);
$catCount = 0;
$currentDepartment = "";
echo "<table><tr><td><ul>";
for ($i = 0; $i < $numRecords; $i++)
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($category);
    if ($currentDepartment != $row["department_name"])
    {
        if ($currentDepartment != "") echo "</ol></li>";
        if ($catCount > $numRecords/2)
        {
            echo "</ul></td><td valign='top'><ul>";
            $catCount = 0;
        }
        $currentDepartment = $row["department_name"];
        echo "<li>$currentDepartment<ol>";
    }
    echo "<li><a href=\"category.php?cat='"
        .$row["product_category_code"] . "'\">"
        .$row["product_category_description"]
        ."</a></li>";
    $catCount++;
}
echo "</ol></li></ul></td></tr></table>";
?>
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data from the query too?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided css or a link, so this is a guess.

I'm assuming your css has a list-style-type set to none.

Change it to

```
ul {
list-style-type: disc;
}
```